# Report "Query By Date" APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle APEX.I want to make report of previous month patients treated by doctor from two tables i-e Patient and History.[image]

Pat_id is Primary key in Patient table and foreign key in History Table.

I want report that should show me  `Pat_Name ,Pat_Age ,Treated_By` and  `Date` where as i can also select month from `LOV`(List of Value) and on the basis of that month it should show me the report.

Kindly Help me out 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.pat_name, p.pat_age, h.treated_by, h.date
  FROM patient p
  JOIN history h
    ON p.pat_id = h.pat_id
 WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM h.date) = TO_NUMBER(:P1_MONTH)
```

(a really basic join condition really)
If you want ordering, you could include this in the sql, or define this in the report definition of a classic report, or as defaults in an interactive report.

`P1_MONTH` : a select list. As for its list of values, you can either define the months statically (12 entries with month number as return value and month name as display), or use a query:

```
SELECT to_char(add_months(to_date('01/01/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'),LEVEL-1),'Month') display_value, LEVEL return_value
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
```

Set the select list to submit on change.

As an extra note: set your column names to be UPPERCASE in your schemas. Columns are always uppercase unless they are defined otherwise upon creation. Also be careful with using reserved keywords for things such as a column name: `DATE` may not be the best name for a column... Give it a useful name such as `TREATED_ON`

Comment: @TOM... How will i make a select list in Report. I can make it in form but i don't have any idea in Reports.

Comment: You don't make a select list in the report itself. You have to create a page item select list to do this. You could attach the page item to the report region, or create a blank html region that will hold this item.